# Single-ended associations are broken in Hibernate, when compared using the equals() method within a transaction context

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, equals, many-to-one

Given below a one-to-many relationship from country to state (the table name is taken `state_table` in the database, since state may be a reserved word in some RDBMS).

The inverse side of the association is given below (I assume the owning side is not required to present).

```
public class Country implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "country_id")
    private Long countryId;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Other fields + getters + setters + constructors.

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.countryId);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        System.out.println("equals() in entity = " + (obj == null));
        System.out.println("this.countryId = " + this.countryId + " : other.countryId = " + ((Country) obj).countryId);

        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        final Country other = (Country) obj;        

        if (!Objects.equals(this.countryId, other.countryId)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

<sub>[`Objects`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) in the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods is a utility class introduced in Java 7 holding only static utility methods.</sub>

The following segment of code uses the `equals()` method in the above entity class as an example.

```
StateTable stateTable = entityManager.find(StateTable.class, 1L);
Country country = entityManager.find(Country.class, 1L);

stateTable.getCountryId().hashCode();

System.out.println("countryId = " + stateTable.getCountry().getCountryId());
System.out.println("equals = " + country.equals(stateTable.getCountry()));
```

The first stdout statement shows the correct value `1` corresponding to the entity's primary key (`countryId` of type `Long`).

The second stdout statement, however, returns `false` incredibly even though `countryId` (primary key) in both the objects is supposed to be the same upon fetching - it is broken.

Those two stdout statements in the `equals()` method in the entity class outputs the following.

```
equals() in entity = false
this.countryId = 1 : other.countryId = null
```

Although the supplied country object is not `null` as confirmed by the first stdout statement in `equals()`, `((Country) obj).countryId` returns `null` surprisingly and consequently, the `equals()` method **always** returns `false` irrespective of what object is supplied as a parameter, since `Object` equals `null` is never true. **This should not happen anyway.**

---

The `@ManyToOne` association is lazily initialized (`fetch = FetchType.LAZY`). If it is turn to `fetch = FetchType.EGAR`, then everything goes just fine. The `equals()` method returns a correct outcome based on the supplied object.

The code is executed under a transaction in a Spring service marked by the following annotations.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

Thus, there should not be an issue of initializing lazy associations. It is explicitly stated in the JPA [WikiBook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Serialization.2C_and_Detaching).

> For collection relationships sending `size()` is normally the best way
>   to ensure a lazy relationship is instantiated. **For OneToOne and
>   ManyToOne relationships, normally just accessing the relationship is
>   enough (i.e. `employee.getAddress()`)**, although for some JPA providers
>   that use proxies you may need to send the object a message
>   (i.e. `employee.getAddress().hashCode()`).

The last statement implies a provider specific behaviour,

> Although for some JPA providers that use proxies you may need to send
>   the object a message (i.e. `employee.getAddress().hashCode()`).

I however, finished trying in both the ways but to no avail.

1. Assigned value of `stateTable.getCountry()` to another variable before passing it to `equals()`). Just as,

   ```
   Country anotherCountry = stateTable.getCountry();
   country.equals(anotherCountry); // Always returns false same as mentioned above.
   ```
2. Used `hashcode()` associated with this association using `stateTable.getCountry().hashCode()` as specified earlier to make sure that the lazy association is initialized within a transaction context before invoking `equals()` and passing through the country object.

While I tried using Hibernate 4.3.6 final (Tomcat 8.0.9.0), this behaviour is not identical on EclipseLink 2.6.0 (GlassFish 4.1) which behaves as one is likely to expect intuitively.

What goes wrong with Hibernate? What is the solution?

Comment: This blog entry should help http://blog.bolkey.com/2009/05/hibernate-datanucleus-r1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand how proxies work. A proxy derives from the actual class, but doesn't hold its data. When the proxy is loaded from the database, another instance of the class (Country in this case) is created, which is a normal instance. It holds the data. The proxy forwards all calls to this instance.

Your code has two potential problems.

- Fields shouldn't be accessed by another object, because it could be a proxy. The proxies fields are not initialized. Call the getters and you get the values.
- `.class` returns the proxy type and not the actual type. It is not necessarily `Country`. Use `if ( !(other instanceof Cat) ) return false` as proposed in [the docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html).

Note that because the proxy forwards all calls to the real object, in your entity is `this` never a reference to a proxy. But every argument you get may be a proxy.

Comment: Do you always use a business key, a surrogate key or something else in `equals()` and `hashcode()` in each and every entity in your projects avoiding the auto generated field on the database side? Business requirements often very greatly and determining a right and permanent business key for each and every entity is difficult - nearly impossible for every entity.

Comment: If I were the only maintainer of an application, I would avoid the fact that a database primary key field must not be used in `equals()` and `hashcode()` to uniquely identify an entity which is nowhere recommended making sure that no transient entities will be stored into a hashed collection like `HashSet` or `HashMap` nor multiple transient entities (after adding them to a `HashSet` on the inverse side of a relationship - `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany`) will be persisted using a cascade persist on the inverse/parent side. If this is frequently required, then using a List will suffice instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't access the fields directly. Instead use the getters inside the `equals` method.